# Another word/phrase for "meticulous"

Tags: word-choice, expressions

I am looking for a word that describes a person's work as being detail oriented.

For example: "His peers had confidence in his meticulous manner."

Meticulous just seems too strong. The latin origin of the word is:

> mid 16th cent. (in the sense ‘fearful or timid’): from Latin
>   meticulosus, from metus ‘fear.’ The word came to mean ‘overcareful
>   about detail,’ hence the current sense (early 19th cent).

And when I use it in the sentence it doesn't seem right. Does anyone have suggestions for a better way to phrase this? Thanks.

Comment: I would venture to say that nobody uses it with the "overcareful due to fear or timidity" definition nowadays.  Everyone I know who uses it, applies it in a positive way meaning *he does a masterful job because of his attention to detail*

Comment: In casual conversation I'd be more likely to say something like: "His coworkers trust him because he's so meticulous."

Comment: Have you tied Googling "use meticulous in a sentence" ? http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/meticulous makes it look like general reference.

Comment: Oh I know it is used often. I was just trying to see if there is a better word for it. It just sounded awkward to me yesterday, just one of those things. It seems like a great choice right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be rejecting a very good word over a misperception. Meticulous does not carry the connotation of fear or neuroses, such as, perhaps, fastidious. In present day English, [meticulous](http://dictionary.reference.com/wordoftheday/archive/2002/12/01.html) usually carries a more positive connotation and is synonymous with *precise* and *punctilious*.

While the etymology of words is fascinating, judging one by its origin is often a mistake. [Hysterical](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hysteric) is a useful word, despite its origin from illnesses of the **uterus**.

Answer (score 4):

If etymology and history were all that mattered, then you might favour *nice*, as it once had exactly such a meaning.

> Precise or particular in matters of reputation or conduct; scrupulous, punctilious.

But then, earlier still it meant "wanton" or "foolish"!

The moral is, etymology doesn't tell us everything. *Meticulous* is fine in the use you want.

*Scrupulous* is too, but is often taken to refer to morality.

*Punctilious* is perhaps the most precise match, but is less well known.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps **[precise](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/precise?q=precise)**

> marked by exactness and accuracy of expression or detail

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is 'conscientious'.